# How to improve page loading?

Tags: performance, rest, google-chrome, http, html

My application has a table of 50 rows, each row makes 3 REST call to the server. Chrome only allows six TCP connections per origin on HTTP 1.
How can I improve the performance?
Also each row of data has a button and while loading if I click on button nothing happens unless all data is loaded (web page freezes), is there a way to have the click of button as high priority?

Comment: Do you mean there will be 150 HTTP requests for your table? Why don't you render the table in server side? Or, at least merge these 150 requests into 1 ajax request?

Comment: @shaochuancs thanks for your response. I am new to this area, rendering from server side didn't help the performance... how can ajax call help? Do u know any good reference that I can read about?

Comment: I think you can start from "High Performance Web Sites" by Steve Souders.